# Split a `dateTime` column into a separate `date` and `time` column in Laravel 5

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-migrations

I have a table called 'offers' with a column called `start_date` of type `dateTime`.

I want to split this column into two separate columns called:

- `start_date` of type `date`
- `start_time` of type `time`

To do this I have the following code:

```
<?php

use App\Offer;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class FixOffersTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('offers', function(Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->renameColumn('start_date', 'start_date_time');
            $table->renameColumn('end_date', 'end_date_time');
        });

        Schema::table('offers', function (Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->date('start_date')->after('start_date_time')->nullable();
            $table->time('start_time')->after('start_date')->nullable();

            foreach (Offer::all() as $offer) {
                /* Cannot use model mutator, as model class can change over time, and may no longer have certain columns
                in the $casts attribute. Therefore using the raw string fetched from the MySQL database. */
                $startDateTime = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $offer->getOriginal('start_date_time'));
                $offer->start_date = Carbon::createFromDate($startDateTime->year, $startDateTime->month, $startDateTime->day);
                $offer->start_time = Carbon::createFromTime($startDateTime->hour, $startDateTime->minute, $startDateTime->second);
                $offer->save();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

However the above gives the following error:

```
[Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\SchemaException]                        
There is no column with name 'start_date' on table 'offers'.
```

However commenting the "for loop" out means this error is no longer present, meaning the issue is somewhere there.

Better methods are also welcome!

Comment: Have you tried taking the foreach loop out of the Schema closure? My guess is the column has not been created yet

Comment: Yes. Same error

Comment: What you are trying to do in the foreach loop is more suited towards a console command. I am not sure at what point the column creation actually completes during a migration, but the error seems pretty clear that is the issue, so I would just run it outside of the migration

Comment: why did you define same function two times?  `Schema::table('offers', function (Blueprint $table)` , can same logic not be implemented in only one function?

Comment: Nope. It's a weird Laravel issue. The reason being is that create columns get executed first so the rename code will results with a duplicate error

Answer (score 1):

Answered my own question. The reason I got this error is becuase of two reasons.

Reason 1, I was asking for a column to be after another column when it doesn't exist yet.

Reason 2, I was creating offers using columns that haven't been created yet.

This is how it should be done:

```
<?php

use App\Offer;
use App\Schedule;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class FixOffersTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        DB::beginTransaction();

        Schema::table('offers', function(Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->renameColumn('start_date', 'start_date_time');
            $table->renameColumn('end_date', 'end_date_time');
        });

        Schema::table('offers', function (Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->time('start_time')->after('start_date_time')->nullable();
            $table->date('start_date')->after('start_date_time')->nullable();
        });


        foreach (Offer::all() as $offer) {
           /* Cannot use model mutator, as model class can change over time, and may no longer have certain columns
            in the $casts attribute. Therefore using the raw string fetched from the MySQL database. */
            $startDateTime = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $offer->getOriginal('start_date_time'));
            $offer->start_date = Carbon::createFromDate($startDateTime->year, $startDateTime->month, $startDateTime->day);
            $offer->start_time = Carbon::createFromTime($startDateTime->hour, $startDateTime->minute, $startDateTime->second);
            $offer->save();
        }


        DB::commit();
    }
}
```